# Bootstrapping heteroskedastic time series

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, heteroscedasticity

My question is simple as stated in the title. How can I perform a bootstrap in a heteroscedastic time series?

Comment: Performing a search for "wild bootstrap" could be a good starting point.